# Draw 3D cube with line loop

Tags: opengl, line, cube

I had faced the problem of using a line loop to draw out a 3D cube by using open gl.

```
void cube1()
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

    //Cube1
    //Face1
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 0);

    //Face2
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 1);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 0);

    //Face3
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 0);

    //Face4
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 0);

    //Face5
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 0);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 1);

    //Face6
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 1);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 1);
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 1);

    glEnd();
}
```

However, I still could not form the correct shape for my cube.Below are my output. Can anyone know the solution?

[image: Cube]

Comment: A line loop is one endless primitive. It behaves different than QUADS or TRIANGLES. Therefore you have to draw 6 separate line loops (or at least 4). 1 for each side.

Comment: or you simply re render one or more lines ... also this remainds me at this: [Draw cube vertices with fewest number of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203833/2521214) so simply just use the found `solution[]` no need to run the solver ... just uncomment the `solution` array and call `draw_pol(pnt,solution);` using my order of points `pnt[]`

Answer (score 1):

A line loop is an endless primitive. It behaves differently from `GL_QUADS` or `GL_TRIANGLES` (see [OpenGL - Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive)). Therefore, you must draw 6 separate line loops (or at least 4). One for each side:

```cpp
//Face1
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0.4, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0.4, -0.3, 0);
glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 0);
glEnd();
    
//Face2
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 0);
glVertex3f(-0.1, -0.3, 1);
glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(-0.1, 0, 0);
glEnd();

// [...]
```